# Partial Differentiation, Vector Valued Function Derivatives

Tags: matrices, limits, partial-derivative

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m \times 1$ column vector.  Vector-valued $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is given by $f(x) = Ax + b$.  Find the derivative, $f'(x)$.

I was able to solve for the derivative of $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, $f(x) = ax^2 + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$.  Not sure how to start this problem.  This is for homework; hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $$f(x)=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}x_1+\cdots +a_{1n}x_n\\ a_{21}x_1+\cdots +a_{2n}x_n\\ \vdots \\ a_{n1}x_1+\cdots +a_{nn}x_n\end{bmatrix}+\mathbf{b}$$ the gradient of the first output is $$\langle a_{11},a_{12},...,a_{1n} \rangle$$ and similarly for the other gradients. So what then would be the derivative?

As far as the interpretation, note that the function is linear, and that derivatives provide *best linear approximations*. In this light the result should make perfect sense.

Comment: I have unfortunately assumed that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, but the generalization should not be difficult.

Comment: Intuition is telling me that the derivative is simply $A$, which makes sense for a linear function.  Sorry for the late response.

Comment: @user2049004 Good intuition! But what are computations telling you? Do you understand where I'm going with the argument above? Computing all the partial derivatives is very easy for this particular function - just do it and see what you get.

Comment: For whatever reason I was thinking $x$ is a row vector.  Matrix multiplication was immensely confusing.  I think I'm all set now, though, thanks.

Comment: @user2049004 Yes, matrix multiplication is highly unfortunate. I think we probably should have adopted a notation where a row vector was written _on top_ of the array, but alas it's not going to change now... ah well.